# Is there any way to set 0 as value for while rather than false? (first week of python) (SOLVED)

Tags: python, while-loop

Below is the code that I previously made for practicing `while` code in Python. It was working fine

```py
x = int(input("what is your waiting number? "))

while 1 <= x:
    
    if 1<= x <=15:
        print("customer number {} please get your coffee".format(x))
    
    elif 15 < x <= 20:
        y = 5*(x-15)
        print("please wait for another {0} min".format(y))
    
    elif 20 < x:
        print("sorry. end for today")

    x = int(input("what is your waiting number? "))

print("error. x should be bigger than 0")
```

But then, I wanted to simplify it and have the last print error code inside the while code.

So I've changed the condition for while to `x` itself (is this ok?), then added an else line with the `print` and `break` code

```py
x = int(input("what is your waiting number? "))

while x:
    
    if 1<= x <=15:
        print("customer number {} please get your coffee".format(x))
    
    elif 15 < x <= 20:
        y = 5*(x-15)
        print("please wait for another {0} min".format(y))
    
    elif 20 < x:
        print("sorry. end for today")
    
    else:
        print("error. x should be bigger than 0")
        break

    x = int(input("what is your waiting number? "))
```

this seemed to work fine when x was either a positive or a negative value.

[image]

but the problem was, when I entered 0 as the value for x, the last print code before `break` wouldn't run.

[image]

I figured that in a 'while' code, 0 is set to false, so `while` x=0 will immediately terminate the code.

Is there any way to set 0 as a value for `while` rather than `False`?

SOLVED
Got an answer, was very simple.
just make the condition for while as True

```py
while True
```

so that it will run without being decided by the value of x.
That case, x = 0 will also be running without problem.

Comment: Did you try "-1" or other negative numbers? Maybe it's just because x <= 0 so the while loop break?

Comment: yes i've tried negative numbers for the new code and it worked. I figured that this only occurs for x= 0 because in a while code 0 is regarded as false. Is there any way to code 0 as a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer** : No.

**Long answer** :

Since you have a `while x` loop, for `x=0`, the code reads `while 0`. code inside the `while` scope is only executed if what comes after the word `while` evaluates to `True`.

Most 'empty' variables evaluate to False, no matter their type. An empty `string`, `list` or `dict`, `0`, `False`...
An operation whose result is `False` also evaluates to `False`, such as `1==3`.

For example :
`1`, `True`, `20<23`, `"foo"`, `['bar', 2]`, *even* negative numbers such as `-10` ... all evaluate to True.
`0`, `False`, `23<20`, `''`, `[]`, all evaluate to False in python.

Note That `None` is a different case. It doesn't evaluate to True or False, but still doesn't execute `while` loops.

Try to execute the following code :

```py
# These will evaluate to True.  

x=1

while x:
    print("1")
    break
    
x=True

while x:
    print("True")
    break
    
x=(20<23)

while x:
    print("(20<23)")
    break
    
x='foo'

while x:
    print("'foo'")
    break
    
x=['bar',2]

while x:
    print("['bar',2]")
    break

x=-10

while x:
    print("-10")
    break

# These will evaluate to False. 

x=0

while x:
    print("0")
    break
    
x=False

while x:
    print("False")
    break
    
x=''

while x:
    print("''")
    break
    
x=[]

while x:
    print("[]")
    break
    

# Special case : None. Neither True or False, but doesn't execute while loops either.   

x=None

while x:
    print("None")
    break
```

It only outputs the truthy values :

```py
1
True
(20<23)
'foo'
['bar',2]
-10
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation sir! Learned alot from this. As for my second code, i figured that by setting the condition for the while code to True will suffice, as the while code will not be decided by the value of x. But anyway, I now realize that you can't set the 0 as a value for the condition in a while code. Really thanks